# Hibernate HQL delete with and

Tags: hibernate, hql, hql-delete

Hibernate doesn't delete my row:

```
public boolean deleteVote(Login user, int pid){

      Session session = getSession();

      try{
          String hql = "delete from Vote where uid= :uid AND pid= :pid";
          Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
          System.out.println(user.getUid() + " and pid: " + pid);
          query.setString("uid", user.getUid());
          query.setInteger("pid", pid);
          System.out.println(query.executeUpdate());
      }catch(Exception e){
```

Outprint:

```
uid: 123 and pid: 1
Hibernate: delete from votes where uid=? and pid=?
1
```

The SQL Syntax is working when I'm trying directly in SQL. Direct SQL Syntax:

```
 delete from votes where uid= '123' AND pid= 1
```

Mapping:

```
<class name="package.model.Vote" table="votes">
   <id name="vid" column="vid" >
   <generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property name="pid" column="pid" />
<property name="uid" column="uid" />
<property name="tid" column="tid" />
<property name="votes" column="votes" />
 </class>
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
  `vid` int(11) NOT NULL 
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `tid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `votes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`vid`),
  KEY `pcid` (`pid`,`uid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `tid` (`tid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

ALTER TABLE `votes`
ADD CONSTRAINT `votes_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `poll` (`pid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `votes_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `user` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON     UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `votes_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`tid`) REFERENCES `teams` (`tid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

INSERT INTO `votes` (`vid`, `pid`, `uid`, `tid`, `votes`) VALUES
(20, 1, '123', 1, 1);
```

I guess it's something pretty easy because everything looks okay for me so far. I got no error or anything else, just that no delete is happening.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that it is not deleted? Did you checked in database or did you do another query in the application?

Comment: checked direct in the database

Comment: Does an insert work for your? Do you have transactions configured somewhere?

Comment: insert is working. I have no transactions in the method. Do I need? //EDIT: Posted the full method to more clear

Comment: I think that there are tow things that you can try. One is to change the capital letter of Vote in the query to lowercase (if you are working with a key sensitive system it can be the problem). And another thing that you can try is to do a query in the application and check there if the problem are the transactions.

Comment: flush the session. query.executeUpdate() is returning 1. This means record is deleted.

Comment: @fiso Vote must big uppercase cause its a class of the model, otherwise hibernate cant map.

Comment: @johny I tried direct before I used the session, no change. Still its rly confusing hibernate find the raw but its still definitely not deleted.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to begin and commit a transaction.

```
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
try {
  // your code
  String hql = "delete from Vote where uid= :uid AND pid= :pid";
  Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
  System.out.println(user.getUid() + " and pid: " + pid);
  query.setString("uid", user.getUid());
  query.setInteger("pid", pid);
  System.out.println(query.executeUpdate());
  // your code end

  transaction.commit();
} catch (Throwable t) {
  transaction.rollback();
  throw t;
}
```

It is also possible that you need to close the session before the changes will be visible in the database.

Answer (score 1):

From the Output you provided

```
uid: 123 and pid: 1
Hibernate: delete from votes where uid=? and pid=?
1
```

it is clear that `query.executeUpdate()` is returning 1. The method returns
the number of entities updated or deleted. This means that 1 row has been updated or deleted, which is okay.

Try doing a `session.flush()` to flush the session, or a `session.evict()` to remove the object from the session.

Answer (score 0):

full java code with HQL & session.update

```
        try {

            try (Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession()) {

                session.beginTransaction();

                String hql = "UPDATE Employee SET " +
                        "firstName = :firstName, " +
                        "lastName = :lastName," +
                        "gender = :gender," +
                        "jobTitle = :jobTitle," +
                        "departmentId = :departmentId " +
                        "where employeeId = :employeeId";

                Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

                query
                        .setParameter("employeeId", employee.getEmployeeId())
                        .setParameter("departmentId", employee.getDepartmentId())
                        .setParameter("firstName", employee.getFirstName())
                        .setParameter("lastName", employee.getLastName())
                        .setParameter("gender", employee.getGender())
                        .setParameter("jobTitle", employee.getJobTitle())
                ;

                int rows = query.executeUpdate();

//              session.update(Objects.requireNonNull(employee));

                session.getTransaction().commit();

                return session.get(Employee.class, employee.getEmployeeId()).equals(employee);
            }

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int deletedRows = 0;
        try {
            session = sessionProvider.get();
            String hql = "delete from ApprovalRemark approvalRemark where approvalRemark.approvalItem.id =:approvalItemId ";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter("approvalItemId", approvalItemId);
            deletedRows = query.executeUpdate();
        } catch (javax.persistence.NoResultException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            log.error("deleteAllApprovalRemarksForApprovalItem exception", he);
            throw he;
        }
        log.debug("deleteAllApprovalRemarksForApprovalItem deleted " + deletedRows + " rows");
        return true;
```