# How to Delete multiple record using where condition in hibernate java

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to delete list of record from my table using hibernate:

My sql query would look like:

```
delete from students where joinDate="2014-03-08"
```

I would like to delete all the record who joined in above mentioned date.

In students table, I'm having two foreign keys: classId and courseId.

Can you help how to write effective way of hibernate delete query for above scenario?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to delete from each table individually:

```
-- Remove all connections from A which reference
-- the B-rows you want to remove
DELETE FROM A_has_B
WHERE B_id IN (1,2);

-- Remove all connections from C which reference
-- the B-rows you want to remove
DELETE FROM C_has_B
WHERE B_id IN (1,2);

-- Finally remove the B-rows
DELETE FROM B
WHERE B_id IN (1,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete multiple records by using HQL as below:

```
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
try {
  // your code
  String hql = "delete from students where joinDate= :joinDate";
  Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
  System.out.println(user.getUid() + " and pid: " + pid);
  query.setDate("joinDate", student.getJoinDate());
  System.out.println(query.executeUpdate());
  // your code end

  transaction.commit();
} catch (Throwable t) {
  transaction.rollback();
  throw t;
}
```

Apart from this you can use `session.delete(student);` method to delete the record

Answer (score 0):

Try this .   [Refer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

[Hibernate HQL delete with and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489281/hibernate-hql-delete-with-and)

```
      String deleteQuery = "delete from students where joinDate= :joinDate";
      Query query = session.createQuery(deleteQuery);
      query.setString("joinDate", "2014-03-08"); //convert date from string
      query.executeUpdate()
```

Pass join date in the query correctly. I assume join date datatype is string . If join date data type is date convert date string to java.util.date using SimpleDateFormat then pass parameter .  [string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)